# Can any one tell me diffrence between below error provider code?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

IDE: Visual Studio 2010, C#  .net application,winforms

I am really surprised that this code **Code-1** works fine

```
    ErrorProvider ef = new ErrorProvider();
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            ef.SetError(textBox1, "asdf");
        }
        else
        {
            ef.Clear();
        }
    }
```

but this code **Code 2**:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ErrorProvider ef = new ErrorProvider(); //changes is here
        if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            ef.SetError(textBox1, "asdf");
        }
        else
        {
            ef.Clear();
        }
    }
```

is not working i.e. its not providing me error handling facility. can anyone tell me the exact reason what is the difference between these two codes. and why the 2nd code is not working fine..

Comment: Looks like ErrorProvider is evaluated in another place. You created a local variable which hides a potential member ef and gets lost after your method is left.

Answer (score 2):

In **code1** you create the `ef` object outside the scope of the event handler and that way the `ef` object still exists after the event is handled, where as in **code2** the `ef` object is destroyed once the event is handled.

Comment: so if i move this code in a function, then will this code work..? and i call this function from a text_changed event

        private void HandleErrorProvider()
        {
            ErrorProvider ef = new ErrorProvider(); 

            if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
            {

                ef.SetError(textBox1, "asdf");

            }
            else
            {
                ef.Clear();


            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: @yogeshkmrsoni why don't you want your errorProvider to be a field of your Form ? That's the "usual" way ! See msdn :http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: yogeshkmrsoni  I'd suggest you read up on how long objects live and when they get destroyed. It'll clear up your confusion I think.

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus There is no specific reason, just wanted to know why it was not working. But GregoryHouseMD has cleared my doubt. Thanks.